# NSButton in Catalina has no selected state

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbutton, macos-catalina

I have an NSButton set as a checkbox with the following code on Catalina (Mojave is fine):

```
let checkbox = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 32))
checkbox.setButtonType(.switch)
checkbox.title = "Sustain"
checkbox.state = .off
self.view.addSubview(checkbox)
```

It looks fine when I load the app

[image: Off]

But as soon as I check it, the tick mark that I expect to be there isn't there

[image: On]

If I load up the visual hierarchy debugger I can see it fine, I've tried putting this code straight onto a new app and it works, but in my app it's hidden, almost like something is overriding it...any help appreciated

It also happens on NSPopUpButtons....no borders :-s

**Update: 14th October 2019**

As mentioned in the comments, it appears it's an Xcode 11 bug, Xcode 10.3 renders the button correctly on Catalina.

**Update: 10th October 2019**

Weirdly, creating a subclass and setting a CIFilter shows the checkbox item, you only have to do this to one NSButton, then suddenly, all the rest work :-s

```
import AppKit

class Checkbox : NSButton {

init() {
  super.init(frame: .zero)
    addFilter()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    addFilter()
}

// add random cifilter
func addFilter() {
    let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor")!
    colorFilter.setDefaults()
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.black.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor0")
    colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(cgColor: NSColor.white.cgColor), forKey: "inputColor1")
    self.contentFilters = [colorFilter]
}


}
```

Doing the same for the dropdown works, but it's invisible until you click it...starting to feel like a Catalina bug

Comment: I also have this issue; with `NSButton` and `NSPopupButton`. However my "Check / Switch" buttons render ok. It definitely seems related to the button styles; since for changing my "push" `NSButtons` to the "gradient" style allows them to draw their borders again...

Comment: As you noted; for me the issue doesn't occur when compiled on Mojave / Xcode 11. Only when compiled with Catalina / Xcode 11.

Comment: I am also having this terrible no good very bad problem with my app compiling on Catalina / Xcode 11. I figured it was some weird beta bug, but it really is a problem in the release version of Catalina and Xcode 11. Has anyone submitted a radar yet?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123710

Comment: I'm running in to this problem, and I've tried a handful of things to fix this.

My project was older and I upgraded it, when it starting having this problem. New Storyboards in the project also experience the problem.

New projects I've created don't seem to have this issue.

I even created a project in Mojave / Xcode 10.3, then brought it forward and it doesn't have the issue.

It seems like the bug is with upgrading older projects to Catalina SDK / Xcode 11, but I haven't pinpointed it yet.

Comment: Our CI environment is macOS 10.14.6 and Xcode 11 (11A420a). I just took a build from there and ran it on my 10.15 machine - by default, the .dmg that is produced is signed but not notarized, so I had to right-click and choose "Open" to bypass Gatekeeper. The app exhibited the weird UI behaviour above. I took the same .dmg and notarized it, and ran it again, and the issue is resolved. I would appreciate if anyone else can confirm or deny that notarizing their app resolves the issue...

Comment: I just exported my app and signed it without notarization and it is rendering properly.

Comment: Xcode 11.2 / Catalina 10.5.1 does not fix the issue.