# Customizing Appearance of NSAlert Checkboxes and Buttons

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

It seems the default appearance of an NSAlert is less than ideal. For example when I click a checkbox, the checkbox disappears, and the focused button has white text.

[Edit] I should mention that this is a Metal app.

Here is the code for creating the NSAlert (using SnapKit for constraints):

```
                let aview = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 70))
                let btn = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Sound", target: nil, action: nil)
                let btn1 = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "Music", target: self, action: #selector(handleMusicToggle(_:)))
                aview.addSubview(btn)
                aview.addSubview(btn1)

                btn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.leading.equalToSuperview()
                    make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
                }
                btn1.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.leading.equalTo(btn.snp.trailing)
                    make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
                    make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
                }

                let alert = NSAlert()
                alert.messageText = "PAUSED"
                alert.informativeText = "BLOKKIT is paused"
                alert.alertStyle = .warning
                alert.accessoryView = aview
                alert.addButton(withTitle: "RESUME")
                alert.addButton(withTitle: "QUIT")
                let response = alert.runModal()
```

Here is a screenshot of how the NSAlert looks:
[image]

Comment: I tested on Xcode 11.2 beta 2 without using sip but creating directly the btn and btn1 frames. I do not get the problem, Music check box is OK. And RESUME shows on a blue background.Try removing sap and set the frames manually, just for confirmation.

Comment: Duplicate of [NSButton in Catalina has no selected state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291431/nsbutton-in-catalina-has-no-selected-state)

Comment: I tried on the 11.2.1 GM seed. Same appearance.

Answer (score 0):

For information, here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I've found that the NSAlert looks fine when creating the project using the basic MacOS template but it looks like my screenshot when you create the project using the Cross-Platform Game template.